# What caused my Linux Mint to reboot?

Tags: linux-mint, crash

My Linux Mint server is running 24/7 and I didn't have to reboot for over half a year. Yesterday I saw that some services were not running and realized, that the machine rebooted earlier.

I'm now trying to find out what caused the reboot but can't find the necessary information.

Here is a copy yesterdays syslog, guess the reboot happened at 22:56:42. 
http://pastebin.com/Gw4FWULQ

(Strange, how not all logs are in chronological order...)

Is there anything in the syslog that gives a hint? 
What other logfiles could I take a look at?

Thanks a lot

Update:
Today, it has happened again. Syslog [here](http://pastebin.com/mbddwuzk). Again, I don't think there's anything in the log. According to 'uptime', it happened somewhere around 21:40.

Update2:
I'm pretty sure by now, this is a hardware issue. I got a few more reboots, mainly when the server was under heavy load. First suspected PSU being faulty, but I then started a few tests with 'memtester' and was able to reproduce the issue. 
During a memtester run, I can see the network link going down and up a few times in syslog as well as one USB drive being re-mounted before the whole system just restarts.

Guess I have to change the RAMs in this case.

Comment: That log looks like your system would have quite liked to send you mail about its problem, but your mail system isn't set up. (By the way, time mismatch can happen if your server does not have a reliable RTC and no ntp client running, so time is only re-checked against a time server on reboot.)

Comment: Good point, will have to look at that. Any chance I can get my system to tell me now, without mails?

Comment: Have you checked emails for root? Simple issue `mail` command when logged as root.

Comment: Yes, did that. No emails concerning the reboot, just a few old emails related to a cron job.